# The Facebook SDK for Swift 4 is outdated. Should I use Facebook SDK for iOS instead?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I found when installing the Facebook SDK with cocoapods that there were several errors in my Xcode project. Upon research I found that this is because the SDK for Swift hasn't been update in a while.

Can someone tell me the best way to implement the Facebook SDK into my Swift application so I can use Facebook Login?

Thanks,
Calum.

Answer (score -1):

Although the errors are still present in Xcode, they do not affect the overall functionality of the program. Therefore, it is okay to simply ignore the errors and hopefully the Facebook SDK will be updated soon.